# Windows 10: how to make "very low battery level" notification popup before hibernating like it was before?

Tags: windows-10, battery, notifications, windows-10-v1703

My laptop with Win 10 used to behave in the following convenient manner:

1. at 10% of battery it notified about "low battery" state
2. at 7% it notified about "very low battery" (*) state
3. after some time, if the charging cable is not plugged in, it hibernated (probably once the level reached 5%)

so once it said about very low battery, I plugged in the cable and went on working.

After some Win update (1703 or later) steps 2 and 3 transformed into a much less helpful scenario: at 5% it sais about very low battery and hibernates at once, so that I can only a) start charging after the low level notification or b) trust my sense of time and start charging a certain period after which sometimes causes that unpleasant gap in workflow due to hibernation.

My question is this: how do I set things to return the old behaviour?

In advanced settings everything seems to be ok:

- very low level → hibernate
- low level: 10%
- critical level: 5%
- low level: notification enabled, no other action
- reserve battery level: 7%

(*) I'm translating back from Russian, so I'm not quite sure about exact terms to use.

[image]

Comment: There is no feature update currently released past 1703

Comment: You may need to work round it: change your low level to 7% and take this as your prompt to plug in.

Comment: @Ramhound but there were some others ("minor" updates) which may broke that

Comment: @AFH yeah, well, that's an option if there's no "real" solution

Comment: Are you sure this is Win10?  Because according to your new behavior, this is EXACTLY what Win Vista and Win5 series (2K/XP/2K3) did.

Comment: @ii-V-Icadence yeah, I'm absolutely sure it's Win10 :)

Comment: UPDATE: You are NOT having a failing battery. If it's W-10, there should be no failing battery.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when my laptop was plugged into a desktop screen and wired internet cat 5 connection, but not when I was using wireless. The cause turned out to be that the same usb / cat 5 hub that connected me to the internet also connected me to the battery backup monitor on my UPS. This caused my laptop to think that it had plenty of battery power even when unplugged because it was reading the UPS, not my laptop battery. Unplugged that connection, and problem solved. Low battery and 10% warning is back!

Comment: That's weird.. cool that you have figured that out in your case, but this doesn't apply to mine..